# Cannot block autoresponses coming in to Postfix

Tags: email, postfix, forwarding

I have an Ubuntu server with Postfix. I only use postfix for outgoing mail, there are no local mail boxes on this server at all. In /etc/aliases I setup forwarders to my gmail address. /etc/aliases looks like this:

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster:    root
www-data:      root
root:          myaddress@gmail.com
```

And of course I ran `newaliases`

I host a bunch of web sites on this server and those web sites send out notification emails when someone is filling out a web form on a site. This works quiet will as SPF, DKIM and DMARC are all configured properly for outgoing mail.

Now about the problem: Some clients are having an autoresponder configured on the email addresses my server is sending out these web form notification messages to. They are telling me that they cannot and do not want to turn those autoresponders off. They are saying, they need those.

When their autorespond mail hits my Ubuntu server, Postfix is forwarding those to my myaddress@gmail.com address. This forwarding works. But I do not want these autoresponder generated emails to be forwarded to to my gmail address! I tried blocking the sender but it does not work. No matter what I do, I still receive these autoresponds in the inbox of my myaddress@gmail.com address. Dozens of these, every day. Again, client will not disable their autoresponders. So I want to block the forwarding of the autoresponder generated mail myself on my Ubuntu server. So far, unsuccessfully. Here is how I tried:

I added these lines into /etc/postfix/main.cf file:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

/etc/postfix/sender_access contains the following:

```
info+noreply@clientsdomain.com REJECT
```

FYI: Autoresponder generated messages are being sent from this address: info+noreply@clientsdomain.com

I ran postmap /etc/postfix/sender_access

I restarted postfix. Several times. Postfix restarts with no errors.

I still receive client's autoresponds in my gmail.com inbox. Dozens of them every day. I cannot block them. Postfix forwards those email to me, no matter what.

Additional info: The original web form notification email is being sent out from my server with the following sender address:

```
From: www-data@myserversdomainname.com
```

Hence their autoresponds hitting my server, as those are addressed to www-data@myserversdomainname.com
Then, I assume, the lines in my /etc/aliases file are responsible for the forwarding of such email to my gmail.com address.
How can I prevent this forwarding for given senders such as info+noreply@clientsdomain.com ?

If you know, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: SMTP envelope `sender` and rfc5322 `From` header content are often but not necessarily related things. Do you want postfix to block based on the former or the latter?

Comment: @anx Based on the From header. As I cannot see the envelope sender... I receive these forwarded autoresponses in my gmail.com account. I save the whole message from gmail.com and I view it with a text editor. I see a LOT of header fields, most are added by google. But I do not see an envelope sender there. So I cannot determine the envelope sender... :(